# How to get a short description of the day of the date in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

While using Python 2.7, I wrote as follows to get a short description of the day. I am currently using 3.6. What would you recommend instead of mx.DateTime to do this?

```
import mx.DateTime

def func(dateVal, format):
    day = ''
    shortDesc = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    if format == '%d.%m.%Y':
        try:
            dateVal = mx.DateTime.DateTime(int(dateVal[6:10]), int(dateVal[3:5]), int(dateVal[0:2]))
            day = shortDesc[dateVal.day_of_week]
        except:
            pass
    return day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the built-in `datetime` in both Python 2.7 and 3.6?

A couple of notes:

- Parse using `strptime`, rather than manually breaking up the string and converting to integer
- The day_of_week almost certainly starts with 'Sun' as 0
- You can use the `strftime` date formatting character `%a` for the abbreviated weekday name, although that will be the local one (rather than necessarily English)
- Avoid using `except: pass`; that will hide a lot of errors that you probably do want to handle or fix or at least know about. Instead, catch specific problems and handle them appropriately (whether that's `return ''` or some other logic)

```
import datetime

def func(date, format):
    the_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format)
    day = the_date.strftime('%a')
    return day
```

Or, in one line:

```
import datetime

def func(date, format):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format).strftime('%a')
```